# React Form not encoding the data

Tags: html, forms, reactjs

I have a simple React stateless component with a form.

```
<form
  action="http://externalsite.com/?param1=value1"
  method="get"
  target="_blank"
>
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
  <input
    className="btn"
    type="submit"
    value="Submit"
  />
  </div>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted the data goes to the external site as

```
http://externalsite.com/?param1=value1&address=word1+word2+word3
```

How do I submit the form with proper url encoding?

```
http://externalsite.com/?param1=value1&address=word1%20word2%20word3
```

Update: I understand I can handle the submit event and manually encode it before submitting. Is there a reason form isn't automatically doing that?

Comment: Have you tried using `encodeURIComponent`? 

<form
  action={"http://externalsite.com/" + encodeURIComponent("?param1=value1"}
...
>

Answer (score 0):

After form is submited you need to create the url string from form data as follow.

```js
(function (address='address', word='word1 and word 2') {

var url = 'somthing.com';
var parm1= `address=${address}`;
var parm2=`word=${word}`;

var url = [url, parm1, parm2];
//here join(&) create a required url
console.log(url.join('&')); })();
```

Comment: I updated the question with the real question I guess. I am able to do the manipulation ok no JavaScript and submit it manually. I'm wondering why isn't form doing that automatically. Usually plain HTML forms do this. Is react screwing it up?